# Query reference documents ODM Doctrine2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two documents `Car` and `Driver`

```
/**
* @ODM\Document(collection="cars")
*/
class Car { 
    /**
     * @ODM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Driver")
     */
    protected $driver;

    //...
}

/**
* @ODM\Document(collection="drivers")
*/
class Driver { 
    /**
     * @ODM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\String
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $name;

    //...
}
```

I want one car driven by "Peter"

```
$car = $dm
  ->getRepository('Car')
  ->createQueryBuilder()
  ->field('driver.name')->equals("Peter")
  ->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

but the previous code return `NULL` even if the `Car` and the `Driver` exist in the database

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6197286/816721) i want to know if this drawback can be solved by other way

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$car = $dm
->getRepository('Car')
->createQueryBuilder()
->where('driver.name =?1')
->setParameter(1, 'Peter')
->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

**EDIT :**

If the driver Peter has more then one Car, you should use 
`->getOneOrNullResult()` instead of `getSingleResult()`